# The value for annotation attribute GetMapping.produces must be a constant expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to implement endpoint for image download. I tried this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/files/{merchant_id}", produces = { MediaType.IMAGE_PNG })
    public void getFile(@PathVariable("merchant_id") Integer merchant_id, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
          File initialFile = new File("/opt/1/Why_Brookfield_Callout_3x.png");
          InputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream(initialFile);
          org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
          response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }
    }
```

But I get error in Eclipse: The value for annotation attribute GetMapping.produces must be a constant expression

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the `MediaType.IMAGE_PNG`, this returns a MediaType object.

The right one you should use is `MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE`, this will return a String.

So you can fix by using this line:

`@GetMapping(value = "/files/{merchant_id}", produces = { MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE })`

EDIT: I don't have reputation to comment on posts, but I would like to know if this method shouldn't return something other than void ?

Best regards.

Comment: I treed it but Angular app received String which is not correct

Comment: Somehow I managed to comment here. So doesn't your getFile method has to return something other than void ?